# Reproving inequality $(1-1/a)^b < e^{-b/a}$

Tags: inequality

I would like to reprove a simple inequality in a different way.
It is simple to see, recalling that 
$$e^x > 1+x \forall x \in (-\infty, \infty)$$ 
that for an $a > 0$
$$ (1-\frac{1}{a})^b < e^{-b/a}.$$ This follows using a simple substitution $x \to -1/a$ and taking the power of $b$.

I would like to use instead another inequality, namely that $e^x > (1+\frac{x}{b})^b$ for $|x|< b$ and $b>0$. How? 
First it is easy to see that I can use the same substitution as before:

$$ e^{-1/a} > (1-\frac{1}{ab})^b$$
But now I don't know how to handle the $b$ at the denominator.. Is this pssible? Thanks.

Comment: sorry i made a typo

Comment: From the initial (convexity) inequality you have $$\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)<e^{-1/a}$$ and you just have to raise both terms to the $b$-th power.